# AA battery voltage as indicator of battery life

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-lifespan

What is a good rule of thumb for the voltage at which a normal non-rechargeable consumer AA battery is depleted? Same question for normal rechargeable consumer AA batteries. Is the answer different for lithium-based AA batteries (as opposed to alkaline-based)?

For background, my question comes from a place of battery-powered electronics, and wanting to prevent my firmware from attempting writes to flash memory when the battery voltage is "too low", in the hope that it will reduce the likelihood of corrupting the file system due to failures in the middle of file writes, for example when a user doesn't bother changing/removing batteries and lets them run themselves to well beyond their useful life.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the loading of the battery, but ~0.9V is usually where the discharge curve for AA/LR6 cells drops off, which means the battery is "dead":

[image: AA discharge curves]

You can see that with a "high" power "personal grooming" device like a shaver, you only have a few minutes after crossing 0.9V before you drop past 0.8V on your way to zero while with a radio it might be an hour (the industry standard tests aren't super exact).  This datasheet is also using 1V as an implied cutoff, but it really depends on your loading and if your power circuitry can deal with voltage that low.  1V might be a good cutoff value if you are concerned about losing data.  Note too that the voltages are measured *under load*.  Open circuit voltage will be close to 1.5V throughout battery life.

There are battery "fuel gauge" chips that will give you a calculated state of charge so you don't have to compare voltage to current yourself.  I believe they're mostly designed for rechargeable batteries but there might be some for alkaline cells out there.

Discharge curves from: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Energizer%20Battery%20PDFs/E91_DS.pdf